# SQL statement for getting user rank in proper order?

Tags: php, sql

I am looking for an SQL statement that returns users rank by score, but does so in order, which is not happening with the code below:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank FROM users WHERE points>=(SELECT points FROM users WHERE uid='$uid')";
```

Instead, each user has the same rank depending on how many users there are.  So if there are 25 users, each of their ranks will display as 25 but this is not actually the case, as surely there must be an individual rank for each user.

I have tried a couple of different of different solutions, but I can't quite put the logic together.  I thought this would work:

```
$sql ="SELECT COUNT(*)-1 AS rank FROM users WHERE points>=(SELECT points FROM users WHERE uid='$uid' ORDER BY DESC)";
```

But I've had no success.

**TLDR;** How could I change my SQL statement to reflect users rank in order by score, without multiple users having the same rank?

Comment: I didn't know if this was supposed to be tagged php or sql, I apologize if I have misplaced this!

Comment: `SELECT user, points as rank order by rank desc` ?  `COUNT(*)` just returns the number of rows in the result, has nothing to do with the points, or user.

Comment: Please show sample data and the expected output.

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$uid' ORDER BY points DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to order the data in the table using the points and give them individual rank you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS RANK FROM users
```

ROW_NUMBER() is not available in MYSQL. You can do following for MYSQL

```
SELECT
@r:=@r+1 Rank,tbl.* 
FROM users tbl, (select @r:=0) as r
ORDER BY users.points DESC;
```

Consider you have data

```
Points
3
7
8
```

Using Select statement with ROW_NUMBER() you will get result as follows

Result:

```
Points Rank
8       1
7       2
3       3
```